# Animating down the position of a UINavigationBar from a UINavigationController - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uicontainerview

I have an UITabBarController that has 3 UINavigationController within. What I am trying to do, is on the push of a button on the UINavigationController's bar, to drop the bar all the way down to right above the UITabBarController's bar. I am doing this so that I can display in a pull down fashion, more content that would fill in the area above the now lowered UINavigationBar and then go away when it is moved up. So, in essence, I want to move around the UINavigationBar of a UINavigationController. I will only need this slide/up down behavior of the UINavigationBar in the root view controllers of the respective UINavigationControllers of each tab. I have tried to just reposition the bar on the UINavigation controller like so...

```
 @IBAction func moveBarDown(sender: AnyObject) {
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 500, width: 100, height: 100)
  }  
  //note that I just used bogus values for demonstration purposes.
```

However, I get something like this...

[image]

As you can see, the navigation bar extends all the way to the top even though it only has a height of 100. This leads me to believe that I am not supposed to resize and move around the UINavigationBar on a UINavigationController and move it around. So, was thinking and researching some other ways of getting this same functionality.

1) Fake it: I was thinking that I could just programmatically insert an identical but "fake" navigation bar not connected to a UINavigationController, hide the real UINavigationBar attached to the navigation controller, and then move the fake one around as needed. Then, on the slide up, I could move "fake" navigation bar back up, unhide the real one, and then delete the "fake" navigation bar.

2) Implement my own sort of navigation controller: I was reading that I could use a container view to implement my own navigation controller. I am not familiar with doing such a thing, and don't even know if implementing my own UINavigationController would be a good thing to do.

So, my question is, how would I achieve the desired functionality of moving the UINavigationBar on a UINavigationController? Is there some way that I am totally missing? Any comments, suggestions, or recommendations are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your research is excellent already, and your conclusions are pretty much spot on. A UINavigationController's navigation bar's isn't yours to move or resize, animated or not. It isn't your navigation bar, period. If you really want a view controller that acts this way, write your own parent view controller (as you very reasonably suggest).

Comment: So, would I subclass UINavigationController, or would I write my own with a container view?

Comment: Nothing about subclassing UINavigationController will turn the positioning of its children over to you. It would be better just to write your own parent view controller. At that point its behavior is _totally_ up to you! You needn't even use a navigation bar in the first place.

Comment: Another possibility is to rethink your goals. I have not quite understood what they are. If the problem is that you want more screen real estate and the tab bar and the navigation bar are in your way, why not just hide the navigation bar? Or why not move the user into a fullscreen presented view controller, where you totally own the screen?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but it isn't exactly up to me. So, if I understand correctly, I have a parent view controller that has the navigation bar and then a container view. I can just push and pop view controllers off and on the container view? Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: "I can just push and pop view controllers off and on the container view?" No, you can't "just" push and pop view controller. Push and pop are features of UINavigationController. If you want them to be features of _your_ parent view controller you will have to _write_ them.